# Parsing table records with Id's and Bootstrap Styles

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Having a challenging applying quotation marks around id's and bootstrap formatting.

The html segment should look like this:

```
<tr>
<th scope="row">1</th>
<td>HOU</td><td>-9.8</td>
<td id="odds-1">2</td>
<td id="place-bets-1">
<button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 pb" id="pick-team-1">Select</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

There should be quotes around

- "row"
- "odds-1"
- "place-bets-1"
- "btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 pb"
- "pick-team-1"

**JS Code**

```
$("#nflteams").append("<tr><th scope=row>" + i + "</th><td>" + response[i].HomeTeam + "</td><td>" + response[i].PointSpread + 
"</td><td id=odds-" + i + "1>2</td><td id=place-bets-" + i + "><button class=btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 pb id=pick-team-" + i + ">Select</button></td></tr>")
```

I read that "\" string "\" should help, but VSC is throwing an error when I apply it to the Id's and the bootstrap formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes around class and id names if you want to use quotes inside quotes

```
$('#sdf').append("<tr><th scope='row'>" + i + "</th><td>" + response[i].HomeTeam + "</td><td>" + response[i].PointSpread + "</td><td id='odds-" + i + "'>2</td><td id='place-bets-" + i + "'><button class='btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 pb' id='pick-team-" + i + "'>Select</button></td></tr>")
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Sometime's I wish there was an online parser to help with applying this correctly. However, your rule of thumbs should be easy to retain.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use single quotes `'` inside a double quotes `"` if you wish to add a quotes inside one and vise versa,

here is link to help you
http://jennifermadden.com/javascript/escapeCharacter.html

```
$("#nflteams").
append(
  "<tr><th scope='row'>" + i +
  "</th><td>" + response[i].HomeTeam + "</td> <td>" + response[i].PointSpread + "</td><td id='odds-1'>2</td> <td id='place-bets-'" + i + "><button class='btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 pb' id='pick-team-''"+i + ">Select</button></td></tr>")
```